# Block someone access from my software if he is using 32bit PC

Tags: python, windows

How does softwares block access when they identify a 32bit PC, and how can I perform this with Python ?

Comment: You can use `platform.machine()` to determine the OS type. What is your reasoning behind it? Do you expect your code to consume more than 3GB of memory?

Comment: @jordanm No, but 32bit computer is using different directories names, and my software is creating a folder in a directory that only exists on a 64bit PC.

Comment: Just compile your code into a 64-bit binary. A 32-bit OS cannot execute a 64-bit executable. No code required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used it, but the [cpuinfo module](https://pypi.org/project/py-cpuinfo/) looks like it should work. Maybe try installing that module from `pip` and then test `cpuinfo.get_cpu_info()["bits"] == 32`